# How to add a Wordpress gallery "link to" option?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I add a custom "link to" option for a default Wordpress gallery? We need that to surround the image with the link to another thumbnail size of that image not with the the original source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add custom link-to options in the current version of Wordpress. It's defined in [wp-includes/media-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media-template.php#L865) on line 865+ without an opportunity to manipulate it.